# Python - list of dictionaries to redis list

Tags: python, redis

I need to create redis list because later I'm going to rpush some data later, 
so I'm wondering if there is any better way to do this: \

Btw, I have already tried set list of dicts and append after get then set to key again,

the following is my code:

```
import pickle
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

connection = get_redis_connection("default")
connection.rpush(cache_key, *[pickle.dumps(data) for data in data_list])
```

Comment: Did I miss something? I didn't see anything special in this. You just push some data into the list. So there's no better way to do this than a simple push command.

Comment: when the list length is over 10**4 rpush will take like 4 seconds, so I'm looking for a better solution of this